# When kotlin flow issues duplicate data 3 times, why does it only receive 2 times in collection?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I ran a basic test on the collect function to learn kotlin flow.

There was something strange during the test, so I left a post

In the flow block, there is a case where 3 identical emit values are entered.
Then, the collected data was output to the log.

Code content:

```
   flow {
    emit(1)
    emit(1)
    emit(2)
    emit(2)
    emit(2)
    emit(2)
    emit(3)
    emit(3)
    emit(4)
    emit(4)
    emit(4)
    emit(5)
}.collect {
    println(it)
}
```

result  :

```
1
1
2
2
3
4
4
5
```

The code does `emit(2)` 4 times and `emit(4)` 3 times.
But the `collect` only contains `2` and `4` 2 times.

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I think you're wrong. In the code, flow and collector are running in the same coroutines so They must work sequentially. They suspend each other if one of them get suspend.

Answer (score 1):

If the log is LogCat (aka Android), then it is because LogCat itself filters duplicate lines out. (Might also be pidcat, but I'm pretty certain it's LogCat). It's all based on the tags being used.

For example, I have a custom DebugTree for Timber where it adds in the line number as part of the tag name.

If I was to do:

```
flow.emit(0)
flow.emit(0)
flow.emit(0)
flow.emit(0)
flow.emit(0)
```

I would see

```
MyClass:1    D    0
MyClass:2    D    0
MyClass:3    D    0
MyClass:4    D    0
MyClass:5    D    0
```

If I didn't use the line numbers in the tag:

```
MyClass    D    0
MyClass    D    0
```

LogCat sees the tag and message being the same, so duplicates are dropped.

Also, it depends on which implementation "flow" is using. If it is using a StateFlow, for example, duplicate values are not emitted.

```
@Test
fun `test flow`() = runBlockingTest {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(0)

    val job = TestCoroutineScope().launch {
        flow.collect { println(it) }
    }

    flow.emit(0)
    flow.emit(0)
    flow.emit(0)
    flow.emit(0)
    flow.emit(1)
    flow.emit(2)
    flow.emit(2)
    flow.emit(3)
    flow.emit(3)
    
    job.cancel()
}
```

Results in:

```
0
1
2
3
```